# cv2 reading video frames causes python generator to delay output till the end

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, opencv, tqdm

I have a python generator that outputs cv2 images (frames) from a video and am processing it using `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`.  I am seeing that tqdm hangs until the generator is exhausted.  However, if I feed the executor from `gen_frames_dummy`, tqdm updates with each task completion.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
def gen_frames(s):
    for frame_num in frames_2_get:
        # skip to frame in video
        s.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, frame_num-1)
        res, frame = s.read()
        if res:
            yield frame
def gen_frames_dummy(s):
    for frame_num in frames_2_get:
        yield np.zeros((16,16,3))
def frame_op(f):
    # process the frame
    pass
with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    frames_g = gen_frames(vid_capture)
    list(tqdm(executor.map(frame_op, frames_g), total=len(frames2get))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`map` waits until all workers are completed and then the results are passed to `tqdm` in your code.

I guess you can rewrite like this to make `tqdm` work as intended.

```
    for args in tqdm(frames_g, total=len(frames_2_get)):
        executor.submit(frame_op, args)
```